# Fancybox (Video) doesnt pop up on desktop but plays on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, video, fancybox

I have followed fancybox instructions.
It seems to only want to direct download the video rather than play it, on desktop. on mobile it plays fine, as you would expect.

Is there some code missing for the desktop?

Links:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="fancybox-media" rel="group" href="vids/shutta_video_portfolio.mov"><img class="thumbnail vidsthumb" src="img/shutta_website_image.png" alt="Shutta Photography portfolio image" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    helpers : {
        media : {}
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.

The script files where located in awkward position, placed at top above other link scripts and seems to have fixed the job.